# Excel VBA- How to Have a Command Button Call on Multiple Macros When Clicked?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to program a Command button in Excel VBA that can call on specific macros based on the string value of a cell. I thought I can just use conditional "if" statements, but there is a bug in the program.

For example, so far I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If Range("F3").Select = "Retirement Age" Then
        Call NewRA
    End If
End Sub
```

And I want the Button to run the macro named "NewRA" when Cell F3 equals "Retirement Age". How can I write the code appropriately to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To start, I recommend using `Range("F3").Value` rather than `Range("F3").Select`.

From there, if you plan on having more than two scripts hooked to this button, I would read up on the `Select Case` construct. Here's an MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx

For example:

```
'... do your setup here

Select Case CStr(Range("F3").Value) '<~ convert whatever is in cell F3 to a String
    Case "Retirement Age"
        Call NewRA
    Case "Another String"
        Call AnotherStringScript
    Case "Another, Even Cooler String"
        Call AnotherEvenCoolerString
    '...
    Case Else
        Msgbox ("Hey! The value in this cell doesn't match a script!")
End Select
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Range("F3").value` , or `Range("F3").value2` , or `Range("F3").text`, or even without a dot `Range("F3")` , but "never" use `.select` or `.activate` (unless no other choice, wich is rare in VBA)